# questions about the nested loop on array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
s = [[0]*3]*3

i = 0 
while i < 3:
    j = 0
    while j < 3:
        print(s[i][j])
        s[i][j] += 1
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

The printed result of the above code really confused me, Why the second and third column of the array become `[1,1,1]` and `[2,2,2]` but not `[0,0,0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you create a list of lists using `[[0]*3]*3`, you're creating one list `[0,0,0]` three times, so you'll have `[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]`, but all of the sub lists (`[0,0,0]`) are really refrencing the same list, since you just created one and multiplied it by 3 to create the others, so changing one list will make changes to the other lists.  
To prevent this, create independent zero-ed lists using a list comprehension:

```
s = [[0]*3 for i in range(3)]

i = 0 
while i < 3:
    j = 0
    while j < 3:
        print(s[i][j])
        s[i][j] += 1
        j += 1
    i += 1
print(s) # just to see the final result
```

Which outputs:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: I see. good and smart way to create the matrix ！

Answer (score 0):

because the way you create array is

```
s = [[0]*3]*3
```

which means all elements of s is the same list and once you change one of them, the rest of them will be changed too
so if you want to get [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]] as you said,try this:

```
import numpy as np
s = np.zeros((3,3))      #in this way you can get a 3*3 array
i = 0
while i < 3:
    j = 0
    while j < 3
        s[i][j] += i     #not plus 1,otherwise you will get [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
        j += 1
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks. you has provided a concise and good way to create a matrix.